# PHP SELECT query of array of named placeholders

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I would like to use name placeholder to pass the value of an array to a select statement, such as:

```
$keywords=("word1", "word2", etc);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE name LIKE :word1 AND name LIKE :word2 etc"
```

Below is the script that I am working on:

```
$symptoms=$_POST['search'];
$keywords = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $symptoms);
$totalKeywords = count($keywords);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_3 WHERE MATCH (symptoms) AGAINST (:symptoms) ";
$like_placeholder = implode(' AND ', array_fill(0, $totalKeywords, 'symptoms LIKE ?'));
$sql .= " AND ({$like_placeholder})"; // build the query with placeholders
// prep input
$where_keywords = array_map(function($value) {
return "%{$value}%";
}, $keywords);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':symptoms', $symptoms);
$stmt->execute([$_POST['search']]);
$stmt->execute($keywords);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Start here: https://www.php.net/pdo.prepare and https://www.php.net/pdostatement.bindparam

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). [Read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) How to Ask a good question.

Comment: Mysqli or PDO ????

Comment: You need to build the query and the parameter array dynamically.

Comment: @Barmar please see my edit question. My issue is passing the variables in an array.

Comment: @Qirel I searched Google and I saw the links. My issue is passing the variables in an array to the SELECT statement. Most Google results are related to MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use both named and question-mark placeholders in the same query. Change the `:symptoms` placeholder to `?` and insert `$symptoms` at the beginning of your `$keywords` array.

You're never using `$where_keywords`. You can concatenate the `%` wildcard in the SQL code itself.

```
$symptoms=$_POST['search'];
$keywords = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $symptoms);
$totalKeywords = count($keywords);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_3 WHERE MATCH (symptoms) AGAINST (?) ";
$like_placeholder = implode(' AND ', array_fill(0, $totalKeywords, "symptoms LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')"));
$sql .= " AND ({$like_placeholder})"; // build the query with placeholders
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
array_unshift($keywords, $symptoms);
$stmt->execute($keywords);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Just needed an extra ")" in $like_placeholder = implode(' AND ', array_fill(0, $totalKeywords, "symptoms LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')"));